# Listening to the Output of a Web Application

Tags: python, web, text-to-speech

I have been trying, in vain, to make a program that reads text out loud using the web application found [here](http://www.ispeech.org/text.to.speech.demo.php) (http://www.ispeech.org/text.to.speech.demo.php). It is a demo text-to-speech program, that works very well, and is relatively fast. What I am trying to do is make a Python program that would input text to the application, then output the result. The result, in this case, would be sound. Is there any way in Python to do this, like, say, a library? And if not, is it possible to do this through any other means? I have looked into the iSpeech API (found [here](http://www.ispeech.org/api#tts)), but the only problem with it is that there is a limited number of free uses (I believe that it is 200). While this program is only meant to be used a couple of times, I would rather it be able to use the service more then 200 times. Also, if this solution is impractical, could anyone direct me towards another alternative?

**@ AKX** I am currently using eSpeak, and it works well. It just, well, doesn't sound too good, and it is hard to tell at times what is being said.

Comment: Is your question specifically about how to generate text-to-speech -> a file with python, or is this about how to deliver the content via a web application? I'm not sure which way to answer.

Comment: There are two ways to put this:
1. How to generate articulated voice with Python
or
2. Using Python to stream the output of a web application that does that already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK. I found a way to do it, seems to work fine. Thanks to everyone who helped! Here is the code I'm using:

```
from urllib import quote_plus

def speak(text): 
    import pydshow 
    words = text.split() 
    temp = [] 
    stuff = [] 
    while words: 
        temp.append(words.pop(0)) 
        if len(temp) == 24: 
            stuff.append(' '.join(temp)) 
            temp = [] 
    stuff.append(' '.join(temp)) 
    for i in stuff: 
        pydshow.PlayFileWait('http://api.ispeech.org/api/rest?apikey=8d1e2e5d3909929860aede288d6b974e&format=mp3&action=convert&voice=ukenglishmale&text='+quote_plus(i))

if __name__ == '__main__':
       speak('Hello. This is a text-to speech test.')
```

I find this ideal because it DOES use the API, but it uses the API key that is used for the demo program. Therefore, it never runs out. The key is `8d1e2e5d3909929860aede288d6b974e`.

You can actually test this at work without the program, by typing the following into your address bar:

```
http://api.ispeech.org/api/rest?apikey=8d1e2e5d3909929860aede288d6b974e&format=mp3&action=convert&voice=ukenglishmale&text=
```

Followed by the text you want to speak. You can also adjust the language, by changing, in this case, the `ukenglishmale` to something else that iSpeech offers. For example, `ukenglishfemale`. This will speak the same text, but in a feminine voice.

NOTE: Pydshow is my wrapper around DirectShow. You can use yours instead.

Answer (score 2):

If using iSpeech is not required, there's a *decent* (it's surely not as beautifully articulated as many commercial solutions) open-source text-to-speech solution available called [eSpeak](http://espeak.sourceforge.net/).

It's usable from the command line (`subprocess` with Python), or as a shared library. It seems there's also a [Python wrapper (`python-espeak`)](https://launchpad.net/python-espeak) for it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: am currently using eSpeak, and it works well. It just, well, doesn't sound too good, and it is hard to tell at times what is being said.

Answer (score 1):

The flow of your application would be like this:

1. Client-side: User inputs text into form, and form submits a request to server
2. Server: may be python or whatever language/framework you want. Receives http request with text.
3. Server: Runs text-to-speech either with pure python library or by running a subprocess to a utility that can generate speech as a wav/mp3/aiff/etc
4. Server: Sends HTTP response back by streaming file with a mime type to Client
5. Client: Receives the http response and plays the content

Specifically about step 3...

I don't have any particular advise on the most articulate open source speech synthesizing software available, but I can say that it does not have to necessarily be pure python, or even python at all for that matter. Most of these packages have some form of a command line utility to take stdin or a file and produce an audio file as output. You would simply launch this utility as a subprocess to generate the file, and then stream the file back in your http response.

If you decide to make use of an existing web service that provides text-to-speech via an API (iSpeech), then step 3 would be replaced with making your own server-side http request out to iSpeech, receiving the response and pretty much forwarding that response back to the original client request, like a proxy. I would say the benefit is not having to maintain your own speech synthesis solution or getting better quality that you could from an open source... but the downside is that you probably will have a bit more latency in your response time since your server has to make its own external http request and download the data first.